# How to define the grid-rows-template in the following: repeating css grid collage layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I need the following layout in a css grid.
There's an infinte number of rows.

[image]

```
.card-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: $grid-gutter-width;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    /*grid-row-template:*/
}
```

Comment: almost the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898785/how-to-repeat-a-css-grid-layout-pattern/52898915#52898915

Comment: Please post all relevant CSS and HTML, so we can see the code you've tried.