# Css grid, large size on some cards, how to place them like this

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm using grid for this layout and I'm halfway through. As you can see number 10,20,30,40,50 gets placed on the same spot (I place them there). I would like to have my layout as from 1 to 10 are

- Large on the left (1,11,21,31,41...), 4 small on the right
- Large on the right (10,20,30,40...), 4 small on the left

NOTE, this list can contain from 40-100 items, so using fixed positions to place it there would not be an option. Also the making nr 6 large and changing the order does not work either due to sorting.

Hope it's clear what I'm trying to do here.

```css
.layout-scale {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.layout-scale__items {
  background-color: aqua;
  min-height: 10rem;
}

.layout-scale__items:nth-child(10n + 1) {
  background-color: deeppink;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.layout-scale__items:nth-child(10n + 10) {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-scale">
  <div class="layout-scale__items">1</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">2</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">3</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">4</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">5</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">6</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">7</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">8</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">9</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">10</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">11</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">12</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">13</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">14</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">15</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">16</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">17</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">18</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">19</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">20</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">21</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">22</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">23</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">24</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">25</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">26</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">27</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">28</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">29</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">30</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">31</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">32</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">33</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">34</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">35</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">36</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">37</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">38</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">39</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">40</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">41</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">42</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">43</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">44</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">45</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">46</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">47</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">48</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">49</div>
  <div class="layout-scale__items">50</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't Bootstrap be better to use?

Comment: @Zhavat, I don't use Bootstrap for projects. There are several ways to solve this ie floats and flexbox (more markup though). I would like to solve it with Grid though.

Comment: you can consider something like this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898785/how-to-repeat-a-css-grid-layout-pattern/52898915#52898915

Comment: @TemaniAfif I had a similar solution with rows and grid but without the `grid-template` Worked fine I just wanted to go without the rows. I have a solution working that I will post. It does go against my own "requirements" but it's no containers so it will do for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have landed in solving it with "fixed" position on `grid-row`. I have a loop in scss that generates it for the `:nth-child()`. The 10 extra classes are worth it compared to the extra markup and css to solve it with a "row" "bootstrap if you will" approach, and even more css for eventually that would be for a fallback solution. For my use case it will not be more than 100 items. If your case use more then 100 items just change the loop times.

```
$increment: 3;

// change the 10 to your wanted amount
@for $i from 1 through 10 {

    .layout-scale__items:nth-child(#{$i*10}) {
        grid-row: #{$increment} / span 2;
    }

    $increment: $increment + 4;
}
```

My full solution is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/batcave/h1xydk2z/) (due to internal code editor does not support scss)

```
<div class="layout-scale">
    <div class="layout-scale__items">1</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">2</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">3</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">4</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">5</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">6</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">7</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">8</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">9</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">10</div>
    <div class="layout-scale__items">11</div>
    ...
</div>


.layout-scale {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.layout-scale__items {
    background-color: aqua;
    min-height: 10rem;
}

.layout-scale__items:nth-child(10n + 1) {
    background-color: deeppink;
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
}

.layout-scale__items:nth-child(10n + 10) {
    background-color: lime;
    grid-column: 3 / span 2;
}

$increment: 3;
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    .layout-scale__items:nth-child(#{$i*10}) {
        grid-row: #{$increment} / span 2;
    }
    $increment: $increment + 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All green boxes start at 3rd row `(grid-row: 3 / span 2)` so they are in the same place.
Also, if I understood the pattern in your mind, you have to use indexes 1,11,21,.. and indexes 8,18,28,...

Try this:

```
.layout-scale {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.layout-scale__items {
  background-color: aqua;
  min-height: 10rem;
}
.layout-scale__items:nth-child(10n + 1) {
  background-color: deeppink;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.layout-scale__items:nth-child(10n + 8) {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

Comment: I left that intentionally there `grid-row: 3 / span 2;`. Your solution works but it's the wrong item that get the position. It has to be 1 and 10, 11 and 20 ect.

Comment: If you want to use css `grid-column` and `grid-row` you need to rearrange your items to match the pattern 1 - 8, 11 - 18, 21 - 28... otherwise if you need to keep the order you'll have to change approach, incrementing the number of tags in your HTML.

Comment: how would that approach be?

Comment: Something like this:

`<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="big">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="big">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="big">11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div>
  </div>
</div>`

The Bootstrap Grid approach.

Comment: not really what I'm looking for, I'll try my approach a bit more. Thanks for posting :)