# multiple widths css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

So I'm attempting to create a grid like this

[image]

Where I have the top and bottom posts the same size and have one post in the middle slim down and auto-fill the remaining space.

Here is my code

```
<section class="posts-grid">
  <article class="post">
    <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

    <div class="blog-listing-info">
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="post">
    <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

    <div class="blog-listing-info">
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="post long-post">
    <div class="blog-listing-info">
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="post">
    <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

    <div class="blog-listing-info">
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="post">
    <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

    <div class="blog-listing-info">
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="post">
    <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

    <div class="blog-listing-info">
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

css

```
.posts-grid {
    grid-template-areas:
    "post post"
    "long-post post"
    "post post";
    grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 385px;
    grid-column-gap: 23px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
  }

  .post { grid-area: post; }
  .post.long-post { grid-area: long-post !important; }
```

I have created a codepen https://codepen.io/ben_bagley/pen/30272c1f61b4f20c080040f5359bd5f1 but as you can see it it's ignoring a good like so

[image]

Any help in getting the desired effect is appreciated.

Comment: you can alternate different sub gird, here is an idea with another layout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898785/how-to-repeat-a-css-grid-layout-pattern/52898915#52898915

Comment: Instead of having two columns, set the grid to, let's say, 10 or 20 columns. Then span grid areas as needed. For instance, the top left item can span 5 columns. The bottom left item can span 10.

Comment: Could you provide an example @Michael_B I'm new to the grid system

Comment: Actually, the correct approach ([per the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) is for you to post enough code in your question to reproduce the problem. We can then work off of that.

Comment: I created a new question here @Michael_B https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877736/css-grid-template-area-invalid-value

Comment: Ok updated this one @TemaniAfif

Comment: Any help @TemaniAfif would be appreciated

Comment: I already shared a link with a similar situation. For me the solution is use nested grid that you alternate

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do not see where that fits in, I've given it a shot but no luck. As said above I'm new to css grid so an example would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

this is the best I could do, I hope it helps.

HTML:

```
<section class="posts-grid">
    <article class="post">
        <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png? 
         width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

        <div class="blog-listing-info">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design 
            much better</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
        <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png? 
width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

        <div class="blog-listing-info">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
        <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

        <div class="blog-listing-info">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article class="long-post">
        <div class="blog-listing-info">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
        <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

        <div class="blog-listing-info">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
        <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

        <div class="blog-listing-info">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
        <img src="https://blog.flyingsaucer.nyc/hs-fs/hubfs/blog/pitchadri.png?width=1464&name=pitchadri.png" alt="">

        <div class="blog-listing-info">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="blog-listing-title">13 things to make your US and UI design much better</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="blog-listing-tag">Design - 11 min read</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

The SCSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
   .posts-grid {
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    .post, .long-post {
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }

    .post:first-child, .long-post + .post {
        background: greenyellow;
        grid-column-end: span 3;
    }
    .post + .post + .post {
        grid-column-end: span 1;
    }
    .post {
        background: lightblue;
        grid-column-start: auto;
        grid-column-end: span 2;
    }

    .long-post {
        background: red;
        grid-column-end: span 4;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

And here is the JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cisco336/ebt0zfvr/